# Google Spreadsheets: how to convert cell values of specific columns into hyperlinks that contain the cell's value?

Tags: hyperlink, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with 15 columns and 3 header rows. There are hundreds more rows containing data, and new rows are being added continuously.

I'm trying to make it so that the cell values of columns C and H are automatically converted into hyperlinks that contain the cell's value within the link, and the cell's value as the hyperlink text.

Ex:
column C, row 300 contains the value `v74k39ch`; it should become: `=HYPERLINK("http://www.example.com/v74k39ch","v74k39ch")`

A Google Apps Script that performs the above should execute whenever data is entered manually or copy/pasted into columns C or H. It should also work with sets of data (such as copy/pasting multiple rows of data from a single column on another sheet to column C or H on the sheet with the script). Note that the URL to be used for column C is different than the URL to be used for column H.

Here's what I've gotten started with and it's not working:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var rng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var val = rng.getValues();
  var col = rng.getColumn();
  if(col == 3) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
      rng.setValues('=HYPERLINK("http://www.example.com/'+val+'","'+val+'")');
    }
  }
  if(col == 8) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
      rng.setValues('=HYPERLINK("http://www.website.com/'+val+'","'+val+'")');
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've attempted to learn more about the JavaScript fundamentals, but I'm not an experienced programmer, and writing this script is proving to be a confusing task. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have done very well.

What you are missing is this;

- The for loops are adding the same string to the range val.length
  times.
- Using set.Values() NOTICE plural "s" is expecting an array, you have
  set a string.  Surrounding it with [] may work.
- If you use setValue() in the code below it will work but you should
  use setFormula() as JKWA mentioned.

Here is the code;

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng   = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var val   = rng.getValues();
  var col   = rng.getColumn();
  var row   = rng.getRow();
  var h_string = '=HYPERLINK("http://www.example.com/'+val+'","'+val+'")';
  if(col == 3 || col == 8) { 
    ((col == 3)? col = "C" : col = "H");
    cell = sheet.getRange(col+row);
    cell.setFormula(h_string);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here, but I might be able to get you a bit closer.

First, I noticed you are using setValues().  This requires setting back a rectangular grid (two dimensional array).  You are setting back a string value, which should work for setValue(), but not setValues().

Next, because you are working with formulas, you might have better results using setFormulas() rather than setValues().

Hope that helps.